# How to reverse multiple lists using the Wolfram-Language

Tags: wolfram-language

**I'm trying to find the best way to solve the question:** "Use Range, Reverse and Join to create `{3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}`"

So basically the given lists are `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}`.

I could easily solve this question but wanted to know **if there is a better way (more efficient)** than what i've come up with.:

**My Solutions:**

```
In[136]:= Join[ Reverse[Range[3]], Reverse[Range[4]], Reverse[Range[5]] ]

In[141]:= Reverse[Join[ Range[5], Range[4], Range[3] ]]
```

given lists: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}`, **where you have to use the functions Range, Reverse and Join to create the expected output**:

{3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

*My solution will not be efficient if there were to be 100 lists instead of three.*

***Thanks in advance for the help***

Comment: @David Bullock ?

Comment: The second solution `Reverse[Join[ Range[4], Range[5], Range[3] ]]` does not generate the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RUNNING EACH ELEMENT OF A LIST THROUGH A FUNCTION:**

```
listA = {}
Function[x, listA = Join[listA,  x]] /@ {Range[5], Range[4], Range[3]}
listB = Reverse[listA]
Clear[listA]
```

**output:**

*result -> listB:* *`{3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}`*

Comment: Hi @ShashaHaven. I found the same-like solution in the wolfram v12 documentation. But i like your little way of Clearing the variable. Cause now you can run that same code in the same instance and listB will always have the expected output.

Comment: Tnx @PhillipJacobs! I saw you had an answer. I tried upvoting it but had to low of a reputation. We're were few that answers these wolfram questions, do you know what ? and thanks for the upvote

Comment: Shasha, i think most people with wolfram knowledge, uses Mathematica as well and I believe they ask their questions on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ ... I'm just trying to learn the Wolfram language so I thought I could ask on here. I saw another guy that seems pretty clued up. @DavidBullock ... I tagged him but not sure if he got the notification. I'll try to tag you next time.

Comment: @ShashaHaven In general, it is more efficient in terms of memory and time to avoid constructs such as `listA = Join[listA, x]` in WL. It is usually much more efficient to use a side effect free functional solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Range[#] & /* Reverse /@ {3, 4, 5} // Flatten
```

> {3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

**Update**

Someone voted to delete my answer without providing a reason. Perhaps because it did not use `Join`. To address that

```
Range[#] & /* Reverse /@ {3, 4, 5} // Apply[Join]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It’s short and powerful but I understand very little of it. Do you have any kind of reference to documentation that’ll explain this characters’ purpose: “#, &, /* ... ...” please

Comment: @PhillipJacobs Take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/58370). And [this](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/preface.html), a nice introduction to WL.

Comment: This is some great links. Thanks so much. I appreciate it so much!